# Regresión: Lasso, OLS, ridge

Tags: r

Reformulo la pregunta, necesito hacer el ejercicio que describo abajo 500 veces (entrenamiento y predicción). Luego necesito almacenar el error cuadrático medio de las 500 iteraciones para cada modelo.
    A la vez, el ejercicio de entrenamiento lo tengo que hacer utilizando 5 subconjuntos de datos de la muestra, en este sentido estoy teniendo problemas con la sentencia de cv.glmnet ya que no se como configurarlo para que lo haga de esta forma, se que por default nfolds es 10.
    Cualquier ayuda es de esencial importancia, tengo que terminarlo antes del Jueves. Gracias!

```
#Generación de muestra de entrenamiento
    ne <- 100
    pe <- 100
    for(s in 1:500) {
      xtrain <- matrix (rnorm(ne*pe), ne, pe)
    ytrain <- apply(xtrain[,1:pe], 1, sum) + rnorm(ne)

    olsreg <- lm(ytrain~xtrain)

    ridgereg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, type.measure = "mse", alpha=0, family="gaussian")

    ridgeregpr <- predict(ridgereg, s=ridgereg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

    mseridge <-mean((ytest-ridgeregpr)^2)

    lassoreg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, type.measure = "mse", alpha=1, family="gaussian")

    lassoregpr <- predict(lassoreg, s=lassoreg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

    mselasso <-mean((ytest-lassoregpr)^2)
    }

    results <- data.frame()
```

Comment: Leyendo el enunciado y viendo el código, no llego a entender que dificultad tienes ¿Como configurar `cv.glmnet()` para un `nfolds=5`? ¿Como generar un set de datos de test (`xtest`)? ¿Cómo guardar los datos de las 500 intreracciones?

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por la respuesta. Necesito saber cómo configurar cv.glmnet para los nfolds=5 y como guardar las 500 interacciones. Quizá luego surjan mas dudas pero por el momento es eso. Mil disculpas por la falta de precisión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación de [`cv.glmnet`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-18/topics/cv.glmnet) podemos ver que cuenta con el parámetro `nfolds` y que efectivamente el valor por defecto es 10, puedes ajustarlo al valor que desees, por ej:

```
ridgereg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, 
                     ytrain, 
                     nfolds=5, 
                     type.measure = "mse", 
                     alpha=0, 
                     family="gaussian")
```

Por otro lado, en el código que has compartido no has generado los objetos `xtest` e `ytest` que necesitas para evaluar los dos modelos. No sé que estrategia vas a usar para hacerlo, podrías usar la misma lógica que utilizas cuando construyes el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento, por ejemplo, para generar 5 observaciones:

```
xtest <- matrix(rnorm(pe*5), 5, pe)
ytest <- apply(xtest[,1:5], 1, sum) + rnorm(5)
```

El otro problema que mencionas, es como guardar los resultados, es decir los cuadrados de la medias del error de cada uno de los 500 ciclos. Puedes crear una lista de vectores fuera del ciclo para los dos conjuntos de resultados:

```
results <- list(mselasso=numeric(500),
                mseridge=numeric(500))
```

Y luego ir completándola usando el mismo indice de cada ciclo (`s`) mediante:

```
results$mseridge[s] <- mean((ytest-ridgeregpr)^2)
results$mselasso[s] <- mean((ytest-lassoregpr)^2)
```

Finalmente tú código podría quedar así:

```
library("glmnet")

ne <- 100
pe <- 100

results <- list(mselasso=numeric(500),
                mseridge=numeric(500))

for(s in 1:500) {

  xtrain <- matrix(rnorm(ne*pe), ne, pe)
  ytrain <- apply(xtrain[,1:pe], 1, sum) + rnorm(ne)

  # Generamos 5 observaciones para test
  xtest <- matrix(rnorm(pe*5), 5, pe)
  ytest <- apply(xtest[,1:5], 1, sum) + rnorm(5)

  olsreg <- lm(ytrain~xtrain) # Esto no se usa, eventualmente puedes quitarlo del ciclo
  ridgereg <- cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, nfold=5, type.measure = "mse", alpha=0, family="gaussian")
  lassoreg <- cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, nfold=5, type.measure = "mse", alpha=1, family="gaussian")

  ridgeregpr <- predict(ridgereg, s=ridgereg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)
  lassoregpr <- predict(lassoreg, s=lassoreg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

  results$mseridge[s] <- mean((ytest-ridgeregpr)^2)
  results$mselasso[s] <- mean((ytest-lassoregpr)^2)
}

head(as.data.frame(results))

   mselasso  mseridge
1  91.14033  6.779988
2  82.03606 23.500737
3  54.54502  9.138695
4 183.60435 17.371076
5 130.50471 12.615367
6  83.93764  8.321154
```

Si tienes alguna otra duda, te sugiero que abras otra pregunta.

Comment: Buenísimo! me sirvió para poder destrabar el trabajo ya que soy un usuario muy nuevo de todas estas herramientas. Las modificaciones que le hiciste al código fueron la clave.

Answer (score 1):

Va una alternativa sin bucles. Más que una respuesta (que ya la hay) es una [solución general](https://xkcd.com/974/) al problema de comparar modelos elastic net con diferentes tipos de penalización. Elastic net es a familia generalizada de regresión penalizada, incluye al lasso, ridge, cualquier cosa en el medio.

En este caso creo que la ventaja de eludir los bucles no que se simplifica el código, de hecho creo que esta solución es mucho más complicado que la respuesta aceptada. Se trata de buscar una solución general al problema y abrir vías posibles de optimización con ejecución en paralelo.

## ¿Por qué?

1. Se basa en una función genérica para comparar diferentes valores de `alpha`. Desde el enfoque elastic net `alpha = 1` es lasso, y `alpha = 0` ridge regression. También se puede comparar con un intervalo desde 0 hasta 1.

Esto es útil tanto para uso predictivo (afinar el hiperparámetro para minimizar el error) como para uso inferencial (diagnosticar o controlar problemas de colinealidad entre los predictores).

2. Al usarse `lapply()` para aplicarlos se podría usar alguna versión paralela para acelerar la ejecución. En este caso vale la pena, porque con datos grandes y muchas replicaciones el tiempo de ejecución se puede hacer largo.
3. Está pensado para trabajar con datos "reales" que podemos pasar como data.frame a la función. `glmnet()` no funciona con interfaz de fórmula y para pasar predictores categóricos es necesario hacer previamente una matriz con variables dummy.

## Función para comparar elastic net

```
#     datos: un data.frame La primera columna es la variable dependiente, las restantes los predictores
#
#     alpha: el tipo de norma de penalización, 1: lasso, 0: ridge, 0 < aplha > 1 : elastic net. No confundir con lambda, que es el nivel de penalización.
#
#         s: valor  del parámetro de penalización para las predicciones (este sí es lambda). 
#            Por defecto penalización valor con mínimo error por validación cruzada "lambda.min"
#            Con s = 0 coeficientes muy similares a los de un modelo lineal sin penalización
#
# prop_train: proporción de datos para entrenamiento. 1- prop_train = proporción de datos tests. 
#
#        ... : argumentos adicionales para cv.glmnet. Especialmente para cambiar la función de enlace.  
#              Por defecto family = "gaussian", modificar si la dependiente es binomial, multinomial, poisson, cox


comparar_enet <- function(datos, alpha = 1, s = "lambda.min", prop_train = 0.8, ...) {
  largo <- nrow(datos)
  train <- sample(1:nrow(datos), prop_train*largo, replace = FALSE)
    y <- datos [, 1]
    x <- model.matrix(~., data = datos[, -1])[, -1]

    modelo <- cv.glmnet(y = y[train], x = x[train, ], alpha = alpha, ...)
    y_estimada <- predict(modelo, newx = x[-train, ], s = s) 
    mean((y[-train] - y_estimada)^2)
}
```

Esta función regresa el error cuadrado medio de un modelo. En sí misma no hace ninguna replicación.

- Separa los datos aleatoriamente en train/test
- Ajustar el modelo y valida por cruces, obteniendo el valor óptimo de lambda
- Predice sobre test
- Calcular el error cuadrado medio

## Test

### Mecanismo generador de datos

Genero unos datos similares a los que se presentan en la pregunta: 100 columnas normales aleatorias, 100 filas train, 100 filas test. y es sumatoria por filas de de la matriz de predicadores más un error normalmente distribuido.

```
ne <- 200# El doble de filas, para después dividir en train/test. Son aleatorios, no debería haber diferencia con el mecanismo indicado en la pregunta. 
pe <- 100 

datos <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(ne*pe), ne, pe))
datos <- cbind(y = (rowSums(datos)) + rnorm(ne), datos)
```

## Replicador

La idea es usar la función `comparar_enet` dentro de una expresión `base::replicate()` para que se encarguen de la iteración. En cada iteración cambian train y test, que es lo que estamos buscando. Además se encarga de simplificar el resultado final y sacar una matriz.

Para comparar los residuos con diferentes parámetros alpha vamos a replicar una llamada a `lapply()` que itera sobre una lista de parámetros. Acá se podría aprovechar para paralelizar con `parallel::mclapply()` (UNIX) o similares y usar al menos dos núcleos. Se podría paralelizar también en `rerun()` cambiando la función, pero está más complicado. No hay `mcreplicate()`.

## Todo junto

### lasso vs. ridge regression

```
library(glmnet)

replicate(10,                                          #Acá va el número de replicaciones. 
          lapply(list(ridge = 0, lasso = 1),           #En esta lista los valores de alpha a comparar, puede ser nombrada o no.
             function(x) {
                comparar_enet(datos = datos, prop_train = 0.5, alpha = x)
                         }
                 )                                      #Termina lapply
          )                                             #Termina replicate
```

### elastic net: de ridge a lasso en escalones de 0.1

```
replicate(10,lapply(seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), function(x) {
  comparar_enet(datos = datos, alpha = x)}))
```

> PD: Para incluir una comparación con OLS se puede mover el parámetro `s` y llevarlo a 0. Ese es el caso de elastic net sin penalización y da unos coeficientes (y por lo tanto predicciones) muy similares a las de un OLS para el caso gaussiano.
>
> PD2: con los datos de la pregunta no es esperable que haya diferencias consistentes entre lasso, ridge y OLS porque los predictores son independientes entre sí (no colineales) y contribuyen en la misma magnitud a generar los valores de y. Eso lo sabemos porque el mecanismo generador de datos es conocido a priori. Si apareciera alguna diferencia definitivamente sería aleatoria.

Comment: Todo sirve! Si bien ya envié la respuesta al trabajo, tu colaboración es muy útil porque estoy intentando aprender mucho sobre este tema. Entiendo que lo mejor es evaluar qué modelo tiene mejor performance predictiva de manera que sólo centrarnos en Lasso y Ridge teniendo como posibilidad algún punto intermedio (Elastic Net) sería ilógico. Asi que usaré esta solución que me brindaste para trabajar en el futuro.