# Fórmula logística con variables dummy con R

Tags: r

Necesito obtener la fórmula de regresión logística binomial para poder predecir si un estudiante abandona o no sus estudios. Tengo varias variables independientes categóricas (EstMadreR con valores de 1 al 8;SitLaboralPadre con valores 1 ó 2). Por lo que averigüé tengo que usar variables ficticias, siguiendo lo que entendí usé el siguiente código:

```
####  IMPLEMENTACION DEL METODO DE REGRESION LOGISTICA  ####

## CARGAR DATOS ##
# Importar conjunto de datos
setwd("D:/PRUEBAS en R/REGRESION_LOG/R_LOGIT")
library(readxl)
mydata <-read_excel ("Ingresantes_2015.xlsx")
View(mydata)
mydata$estado01 <- as.factor(mydata$estado01) 
mydata$EstMadreR<-as.factor(mydata$EstMadreR)
mydata$SitLaboralPadre<-as.factor(mydata$SitLaboralPadre)
## FORMAR CONJUNTOS DE ENTRENAMIENTO/ PRUEBA   
sample <-sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(mydata), replace=T, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train<-mydata[sample,] # datos de entrenamiento
test<-mydata[!sample,] # datos de prueba
## CONSTRUIR EL MODELO CON VARIABLES SELECCIONADAS (datos de entrenamiento)
formula1<-estado01~Regulares + Edad + EstMadreR + SitLaboralPadre 
model1<-glm(formula1, family="binomial",data=train)
# Resultados del modelo
summary(model1)
```

**Esto está bien??**

Como resultado obtuve:
[image: Resultados Regresión Logística]

**Mi problema es que no sé cómo plantear la ecuación de regresión**. Si todas las variables serían numéricas, la expresión sería: Z1=-5.91688+1.27889*Regulares+0.06152*Edad+.....
Pero **cuando tengo variables ficticias es igual???. Se debe incorporar todas las variables ficticias o sólo las significativas?? a qué variables toma R como categoría de referencia??.** Por favor si alguien puede orientarme o indicarme dónde buscar info ya que busqué en la web y no encontré nada al respecto en R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema de los predictores categóricos que entran un modelo como variables dummie es independiente de que el modelo sea OLS (con $y$ numérica) o un modelo logit, con bien señala @Fede. El logit cambia el lado izquierdo de la ecuación de regresión, el lado derecho queda igual.  Sin embargo se interpreta diferente y la ecuación es diferente.

Voy punto por punto:

1. En `R` no es necesario crear las variables dummie (one hot coding) para un modelo lineal. Con incluir un término de regresión en la fórmula y que este en los datos sea de la clase `factor` `R` lo hace automáticamente.  En ese sentido, tu código está bien, a pasar a factor la llamada a `glm()` se encarga de expandir la matriz del modelo. Podrías hacerlo aparte con `model.matrix()` pero no tiene mucho sentido en este caso.
2. Cuando trabajas con una variable categórica convertida a dummie, como bien lo señalas, una categoría queda como "referencia". En sentido estricto esa categoría se estima en la ordenada al origen, porque es $x=0$. Ese es el chiste de la codificación dummie. El modelo va a estimar una pendiente para todas las demás categorías de la variable *con respecto a la ordenada al origen* o constante.
3. Derivado de 1 y 2: por convención el primer nivel del factor es el que pasa a la ordenada al origen o referencia. Con el data.frame limpio y ya pasados a factor puedes usar `sapply(df, levels)` para identificar cuál es el primer nivel en cada caso. `constrasts()` te permite hacerlo una variable por vez.
4. Para escribir la ecuación es necesario reportar **todos** los términos que especificaste en el modelo.

   - Es necesario reportarlos independientemente del resultado de la prueba de hipótesis. Aunque la prueba de hipótesis te indique que no podrías distinguirlos de 0 a los efectos de la estimación de un valor de $y$ esas pendientes entran en el cálculo.
   - Por la codificación dummie tendrás un término por cada categoría de las variables categóricas, excepto el primer nivel que está implícito en la constante del modelo. Vas tener muchos más términos en el modelo de los que tendrías en un modelo con predictores numéricos.
   - Si quieres que efectivamente se conviertan en coeficientes 0 investiga sobre los modelos lasso. Eso es exactamente lo que hacen, penalizar y reducir coeficientes hasta llevarlos a 0. Para *modelado predictivo* dan igual o mejor resultado que un lineal generalizado y reducen mucho la complejidad el reducir el número de predictores efectivos. Compactar categorías pueda ayudar en algunos casos, pero tiene sus riesgos porque hay pérdida de información.
5. Como el modelo es logit las pendientes son un poco complicadas de interpretar. Son el logaritmo de la razón de probabilidad de $y = 1$ vs. $y = 0$. Si quieres dejar las pendientes con salen del modelo entonces deberías aclararlo en lado izquierdo de la ecuación. El modelo en su forma básica ya no sería $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1+\epsilon$ sino que sería $$ln(\frac{p1}{1-p1}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1+\epsilon$$ De este modo ya se sabe que para estimar el valor esperado de $y$ tenemos que hacer una transformación.

La ecuación genérica:

[image: ecuación logit]

Algo adaptado a tus datos, tomando los coficientes que incluyes en la pregunta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Suerte y no dudes en poner un comentario a la respuesta si hay algo en lo que no me expliqué bien.

Comment: Muchasss Graciass!!. Si entendí bien entonces la ecuación puede ser usada para predecir la probabilidad de que un alumno abandone sus estudios de esta forma:
Si Z1=ln⁡(p_desertor/p_nodesertor ); entonces  〖P(y=desertor)〗=1/(1+exp⁡(-Z1))?? esto estaría correcto??. Lo que no me quedó claro es lo siguiente: "Si quieres que efectivamente se conviertan en coeficientes 0 investiga sobre los modelos lasso". Otra vez muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te interesa hacer la predicción/clasificación lo mejor es usar directamente la función `predict()`, que tiene un método para modelos logit. La sintaxis sería algo así como `predict(model1, newdata=test, type = "response")` . Eso si quieres estimar sobre los valores del grupo tratamiento, que entiendo se llama test. Al usar `type = "response"` vas a obtener la probabilidad de que esa fila sea y = 1, es decir, la segunda categoría del factor dependiente. Digamos, `desertor`,  si tus levels son `[1] no desertor [2] desertor`. Eso es más interpretables que el exponencial.

Comment: Si quieres hacer una clasificación binaria deberías especificar un criterio de corte. Por ejemplo: si el valor estimado de y es > 0.5 desertor, si ^y<0.5 no desertor. En este sitio puedes buscar preguntas/respuestas sobre la función `predict()`. También puedes usar `help(predict.glm)` en la consola de R para ver la ayuda.

Comment: Sobre modelos con penalización de coeficientes, esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271284/regresión-lasso-ols-ridge puede darte un punto de partida. Básicamente son modelos similares a un OLS o generalizado que agregan una penalización a los coeficientes en función de minimización de residuos. La idea es obtener el mejor modelo posible con los coeficientes más pequeños posibles. En el caso del lasso eso implica que algunos coeficientes se reducen a 0. Teóricamente la ventaja es que se reduce el sobreajuste a los datos de entrenamiento y se logra mejor predicción vs OLS

Comment: Uy sorry x tantos comentarios :( pero parece que hice mal muchas cosas. Yo construí la matriz  de confusión con la función predict(): pred_valid <- predict(model1, type = 'response', newdata = test)
pred_valid <- ifelse(pred_valid > 0.5, 1, 0).....
Lo que necesito hacer es: dados ciertos valores por ej 'Regulares'=3,'Edad'=23,' EstMadreR'= Secundario, 'SitLaboral' =No trabaja, poder decir que los estudiantes con similares características  tienen 'x' probabilidad de 'Continuar sus estudios'. Alli tendría que usar predict()?? yo entendí que podía usar la fórmula base. Slds

Comment: La matriz de confusión aplica a la *clasificación*, que es binaria: desertor-no desertor. Es una forma de validar tu modelo ¿cuantos errores comete en grupo test? Lo que te da `predict()` es una *estimación*,la probabilidad de desertor condicional a los valores en las variables independientes. Llegado el caso podrías usar un criterio de corte para pasar de esta probabilidad a una clasificación cerrada.

Comment: Si tu modelo *ya está validado* y estás conforme con su capacidad predictiva podrías usarlo para estimar la probabilidad de deserción en datos que no existen en tu data set. En ese caso tendrías que crear un data.frame con datos artificiales (tipo 'Regulares'=3,'Edad'=23,' EstMadreR'= Secundario, 'SitLaboral' =No trabaja) y usar `predict()` sobre esos datos con el argumento `newdata =` y ver que está estimando. Después quedarte con la probabilidad que te regresa o usarla para imputar un resultado binario con tu criterio de corte. Se puede hacer la fórmula a mano, pero es mejor usar `predict()`

Comment: Muuchass gracias Palladino!, voy a averiguar más sobre la función predict(). Slds

Answer (score 0):

Hola con que solo una de las variables indicadoras resulte significativa deberías incluir todas las otras (siempre hablando por cada variable categórica). Por ejemplo, si decidís incluir EstMadreR en el modelo deberías dejar las 8 variables indicadoras que se generaron.
Para conocer como codificó R las variables indicadoras podes usar

```
contrasts(EstMadreR)
contrasts(SitLaboralPadre)
```

Una posibilidad que podes plantearte es recodificar las variables de 0 a 7 y 0 a 1 para que así poder tomar uno de los niveles como referencia, ya que con la codificación actual los coeficientes te están indicando la diferencia media respecto al Intercept.
En los casos en que muchas indicadoras resulten no significativas también podrías plantearte colapsar categorías.
La idea general de las variables indicadoras en la misma que para el caso de regresión lineal simple, que quizás te resulte mas fácil encontrar más información que para para regresión logística.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Fede por responder. La implementación del método está bien? crear las variables ficticias de esta manera: mydata$EstMadreR<-as.factor(mydata$EstMadreR), es correcto??